# How to get path of a file in another folder using os python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, backend, filepath

Let's say this is my folder structure,

```
project
    main_folder
         file.py
    json_files_folder
         one.json
         two.json
         three.json
```

When I run the `file.py` file it should fetch the path of the files in `json_files_folder` and open a file,
Here is my code,

```
import json
import os


try:
    file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = file_path + '/' + 'one' + '.json'
    with  open(filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
except:
     return "error"
```

what should I change in file_path variable to make this code work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this `import os
p = os.path.abspath('..')` if you need the answer please comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json` files are present in `json_files_folder` hence you need to traverse to that path to get the `json` files. Here is the code for the same:

```
import json
import os


try:
    file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = file_path + '/../json_files_folder/one.json'
    with  open(filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    print (data)
except Exception as ex:
     raise ex
```

Comment: Besides the solution itself changing the exception handler was a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use `Pathlib.Path`.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path


try:
    base = Path(__file__).parent.parent
    filename = base / 'json_files_folder' / 'one.json'
    with  open(filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    print(data)
except:
     return "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, use shorter option:

```
import json
import os

try:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(os.pardir, "json_files_folder", "one.json")
    with  open(path_to_file) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    print(data)
except:
    print("An error occured")
```